# Obtengo error al calcular IVA por medio de un evento click

Tags: java, android

Estoy obteniendo el error en la linea numero 124 al ejecutar el método `onClick` que contiene el método `calibrarIVA()` este es el error anexo `.java` donde se encuentra el método...

```
    PID: 28537
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,95"
            at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
            at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:511)
            at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:618)
            at pv.portafolioverde.pruebafacturacion.MainActivity.calibrarIVA(MainActivity.java:124)
            at pv.portafolioverde.pruebafacturacion.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:475
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5661)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22682)
```

Aquí el método:

```
calibrarIVA(){
                    Double sub = Double.valueOf(subtotal.getText().toString());
                    Double ivaT = sub*0.19;
                    DecimalFormat dfi = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                    String ivas = new Double(dfi.format(ivaT)).toString();
                    tviva.setText("Iva: "+ivas);
                    Double imp = Double.valueOf(impuesto.getText().toString());
                    Double ret = 
                    Double.valueOf(retefuente.getText().toString());
                    Double tot=sub+imp+ivaT-ret;
                    DecimalFormat dft = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                    String totales = new Double(dft.format(tot)).toString();
                    tvtotal.setText("Total: "+totales);
   }
```

Tambien intente cambiar esa linea 124 por esta :

```
String totales = Double.valueOf(dft.format(tot)).toString();
```

Agrego también el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pv.portafolioverde.pruebafacturacion">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PrincipalMenu" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".log_in" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: no lo he revisado, pero los decimales son con punto, no con coma, prueba agregandole un replace(",",".") antes de parsearlo, algo así como

Double sub = Double.valueOf(subtotal.getText().toString().replace(",",".");

Comment: Hola @AndresMora ya revisaste la respuesta que agregué, trata de comentar para de esta forma poder ayudarte, saludos!.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya encontré una solución alterna y me funciona en todas la versiones de android ya que las anteriores respuestas solo funcionan en ciertas versiones de Android. Agrego al final el código de mi solución y actualmente funcional.

Comment: @AndresMora la solución no va en la pregunta, para eso en la parte inferior existe la zona de respuestas donde la puedes publicar por favor

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mi solucion fue esta, ya que con las respuestas anteriores tuve dificultades en diferentes versiones de Android:

```
float subT = Float.parseFloat(subtotal.getText().toString());
                        double ivaFTS = subT*(0.19);
                        tviva.setText(""+ivaFTS);
                        float impF = Float.parseFloat(impuesto.getText().toString());
                        float retF = Float.parseFloat(retefuente.getText().toString());
                        double tvTotalFTS = subT+impF+ivaFTS-retF;
                        tvtotal.setText(""+tvTotalFTS);
```

Comment: ¿Que dificultades tuviste, las clases usadas no tienen conflictos entre versiones de sistema operativo android?, si en los valores de los editText por ejemplo "impuesto.getText().toString()" se tuviera un valor null o no numérico, tu aplicación se cerraría.

Comment: Si la repuesta no es la correcta, porque marcarla con palomita ?

Comment: Si es la correcta, solo la publiqué ya que ha alguien le puede interesar, con el metodo corrigeFormato tampoco funciona ya que las funciones como DecimalFormat y .valueof no se dan muy bien en versiones de android 4 o 5 incluso en Andriod 6 o utlilizando otras llamados por medio de String, creo que la forma correcta para mi en este caso fue utlizando en vez de Doubles cambio a Float y luego la funcion de Float.parseFloat(String string);

Comment: Un poco extraño lo que comentas el uso de DecimalFormat y .Double.valueof() no debería tener insonsistencias entres versiones de sistema operativo =/.

Comment: Lo peor es que dice el OP que no se dan muy bien y nos quedamos sin saber qué quiere decir. ¿No compila? ¿No lee el dato?

Answer (score 7):

El problema es el valor que se tiene en los `EditText` tiene un formato el cual no se puede convertir a `Double`, ejemplo:

```
Double.valueOf("0,95")  //Incorrecto
```

Para poder convertirlo usa "." en lugar de ",".

Para esto te sugiero agregar un método para corregir el formato del valor que se agregue en los `EditText`, también validar el caso en el cual la cadena tiene valor `null` o no es numérica retornar un valor por defecto en este caso puede ser 0:

```
public String corrigeFormato(String valor){

    //Si el valor es diferente de null, y contiene , lo reemplaza por .
    if(valor != null && valor.contains(",")) {
        valor = valor.replace(",", ".");
    }

    //Si el valor es diferente de null y es numérico, retorna el valor.
    if(valor != null && valor.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+")){
        return valor;
    }else{ //Si es null o no es numérico, retorna 0.
        return "0";
    }


}
```

y úsalo de esta forma en tu código:

```
calibrarIVA(){
    Double sub = Double.valueOf(corrigeFormato(subtotal.getText().toString()));
    Double ivaT = sub*0.19;
    DecimalFormat dfi = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    String ivas = new Double(dfi.format(ivaT)).toString();
    tviva.setText("Iva: "+ivas);
    Double imp = Double.valueOf(corrigeFormato(impuesto.getText().toString()));
    Double ret =
            Double.valueOf(corrigeFormato(retefuente.getText().toString()));
    Double tot=sub+imp+ivaT-ret;
    DecimalFormat dft = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    String totales = new Double(dft.format(tot)).toString();
    tvtotal.setText("Total: "+totales);
}
```